# I am getting ValueError in the script

Tags: python, argv

I am getting `valueError` in this code.
I do not know why?

```
from sys import argv
(script,first,second,third)=argv

print('The script is called:',script)
print('The first variable is :',first)
print('The second variable is :',second)
print('The third variable is :',third)
```

Comment: Maybe the reason is in the error message.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post the exact errormessage and the arguments you pass to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You're either not providing enough arguments to run your script or providing too many arguments, you need to provide three arguments like this:

```
python3 script.py first second third
```

Comment: @ShankarDayalMishra Your welcome. If my answer helped please submit it as the correct answer.